# Difference between error, abort, assert and fail?

Tags: daml

What is the difference between `error`, `fail`, `abort` and `assert` in DAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fail` and `abort` are aliases for the same function, with `abort` being the more common use. They are used to fail an `Action` like `Update` and `Scenario`, but still return a value of the appropriate type. The following scenario is perfectly fine, since `s` is never actually performed:

```
t = scenario do
  let
    s : Scenario () = abort "Foo"
  return ()
```

When you want a branch of a `Scenario` or `Update` to cause failure, use `abort`. For example, the following `Scenario` will succeed or fail depending on the value of `abortScenario`:

```
t2 = scenario do
  let abortScenario = True
  if abortScenario
    then abort "Scenario was aborted"
    else return ()
```

`assert` is just a wrapper for `abort`:

```
-- | Check whether a condition is true. If it's not, abort the transaction.
assert : CanAbort m => Bool -> m ()
assert = assertMsg "Assertion failed"

-- | Check whether a condition is true. If it's not, abort the transaction
-- with a message.
assertMsg : CanAbort m => Text -> Bool -> m ()
assertMsg msg b = if b then return () else abort msg
```

It's almost always better to use `abortMsg`, as you can supply an informative error message.

`error` is used to define partial functions. It does not return a value, but causes the interpreter to exit immediately with the given error message. E.g.

```
divide : Int -> Int -> Int
divide x y
  | y == 0 = error "Division by Zero!"
  | otherwise = x / y
```

DAML is eagerly executed so you have to be very careful with `error`. The below scenario will fail, even though `e` is not used.

```
s = scenario do
  let
    e = divide 1 0
  return ()
```